# Share a data volume between two docker containers

Tags: apache, jenkins, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I use Docker version 1.13.1,build 092cba3 on Windows 10.

I have a custom Jenkins container that builds code from Github in a volume.

The volume is `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myjob` .

I also have an Apache container that I want to share the volume with.

The `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
version: '2'

services:

  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins:v1
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false" # Start jenkins unlocked
    ports:
  #    - "50000:50000" # jenkins nodes
      - "8686:8080" # jenkins UI
    volumes:
      - myjob_volume:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myjob

  apache:
    container_name: httpd
    image: httpd:2.2
    volumes_from:
      - jenkins

volumes:
  myjob_volume:
```

I basically want the Jenkins container to fetch the code in a volume , which will then be visible by the Apache (httpd) container. So every change I make to the code from my IDE and pushed to Github, will be visible in the Apache container. The volume is created in the Apache container, but when I successfully build the code in the Jenkins container, it does not appear in the volume in Apache.

**EDIT:**
After launching the 2 containers with `docker-compose up -d`,

- I enable their volumes from Kitematic
- I change the volume path for Apache to point to the Jenkins volume
- and when I build the code from Jenkins, Apache sees it as I would like.

So...how should I do the same from the `docker-compose` file ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `volumes_from` which "copies" the mount definition from the container you're specifying. As a result, the `myjob_volume` will be mounted at `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myjob` inside the Apache container. The official Apache image from Docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) uses `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/` as the webroot.

To mount the volume at that location, update the docker-compose file to look like this;

```yaml
version: '2'

services:

  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins:v1
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false" # Start jenkins unlocked
    ports:
  #    - "50000:50000" # jenkins nodes
      - "8686:8080" # jenkins UI
    volumes:
      - myjob_volume:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myjob

  apache:
    container_name: httpd
    image: httpd:2.2
    volumes:
      - myjob_volume:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

volumes:
  myjob_volume:
```

Comment: does it have to be `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/` ? Couldn't just be something like `/var/test` and be the same thing?

Comment: Sure, that should be possible, but you'll have to provide a custom configuration file for apache

Comment: The example in this answer is basically the same as the  two-service setup `data-volume` example in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference).